# Android app won't build -- Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01

Tags: android

One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\FH Robin.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2fe0da45b03df28ba671dbf6eb8a99c3\transformed\work-runtime-2.7.0-beta01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Tried using `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0` but that caused all sorts of other issues. Reverted back to `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha05` and haven't had an issue. Try different `androidx.work:work-runtime:` versions and see what works.